# matplotlib share xaxis with yaxis from another plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I want to tie the x and y axis of two separate axes together so that they zoom together I usually do something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
```

But I don't know how to share the xaxis of one plot with the yaxis of another plot. For example the xaxis of one plot is 'time' and I want to share that with the yaxis of another plot which also represents 'time'. Something like this (which doesn't work...):

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,sharex=ax1.yaxis, sharey=ax1.xaxis)
```

Comment: Sharing via the subplot constructor won't work as you noted, but you can always use `get` and `set` after you make the axes. You could try `ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_ylim())`

Comment: Do you need this sharing only for subplot creation or also for interactive zooming, panning etc?

Comment: This if for interactive zooming and panning. I am currently getting around this by connecting to the ylim_changed callback: `ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', on_ylims_changed)` and then updating things that way, but it seemed like there might be an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would be doing something like this,

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True) //Here
fig.suptitle('Sharing both axes')
axs[0].plot(x, y ** 2)
axs[1].plot(x, 0.3 * y, 'o')
axs[2].plot(x, y, '+')
```

As per matplotlib docs and works fine for me too

Another way is you can superimpose too.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually set the axes properties after all the plotting is done:

```py
def sharexy(ax1, ax2):
    ax2.set_ylim(*ax1.get_xlim())
    ax2.set_yticks(ax1.get_xticks())

data = [i**2 for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(6, 2))

ax[1].plot(data)
ax[1].set_xticks([0.0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10.0])

sharexy(ax[1], ax[0])
```

Any other thing that needs to be shared between the axes can be looked up using `.get_` method and set using the `.set_` method. These will go in the `sharexy` function and should be called at the end of the plot generation.

This is what the above generates:

[image]